# Instant abortion functionality for an arbitrary function that takes time to execute?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, cancellation

I'm experiencing difficulty creating an "abortion function" for a looping function that takes significant time to execute, in JavaScript. My goal is to be able to have some stimulus (or one of a few different stimuli) immediately terminate the looping function and run some shutdown sequence instead. While I could obviously accomplish this by having conditional break/return statements all throughout the looping function that constantly check the abort condition(s), surely there must be a cleaner, easier-to-maintain way to accomplish this (async maybe)?

Below is some skeleton code to clarify the situation:

```js
// Func() runs until some stimulus occurs, such as
// a key being pressed or a condition being met,
// after which it immediately stops in its tracks
// and Abort() runs instead

function Func() {
    while (true) {
        // Does a bunch of complicated stuff.
        // Probably calls other functions,
        // maybe has some Time.sleep() calls in there.
    }
}

function Abort() {
    // Shuts down whatever procedure was being performed
    // in Func() and terminates
}
```

I'm sure that the solution to this is simpler than I think, but I appreciate any input nevertheless!

Comment: Why not add a `var keepRunning = true` outside of both functions, set your `while (keepRunning)`, and then set keepRunning to false in abort() whenever you want to kill it?

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous here. I don't think you can externally interrupt a synchronous execution

Comment: `Time.sleep()` is not javascript though (or are you developing on a hardware board?). It also depends on what other functions are being called inside Func. If there is another loop in there you can't stop it unless that loop also has a check.

Comment: See that `while(true)` statement.  Imagine if the function accepted a parameter of type `{abort:bool}` and the statement was `while(!arg.abort)`.  I think that's the obvious solution you were referring to and you're probably not going to find a more straightforward way to handle it.  

JavaScript executes in a single-threaded event loop, so there isn't any part of the runtime that could really cancel the execution from outside of the function.